# Elasticsearch Terms Aggregation on array -- filter to buckets that match your query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using a elasticsearch `terms` aggregation to bucket based on an array property on each document. I'm running into an issue where I get back buckets that are *not* in my query, and I'd like to those filter out.

Let's say each document is a `Post`, and has an array property media which specifies which social media website the post is on (and may be empty):

```
{
   id: 1
   media: ["facebook", "twitter", "instagram"]
}
{
   id: 2
   media: ["twitter", "instagram", "tiktok"]
}
{
   id: 3
   media: ["instagram"]
}
{
   id: 4
   media: []
}
```

And, let's say there's another index of `Users`, which stores a `favorite_media` property of the same type.

```
{
  id: 42
  favorite_media: ["twitter", "instagram"]
}
```

I have a query uses a `terms lookup` to filter, then does a `terms` aggregation.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filter": {
            "terms": {
                "index": "user_index",
                "id": 42,
                "path": "favorite_media"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "Posts_by_media": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "media",
                "size": 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will result in:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "Posts_by_media": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,   
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,           
      "buckets": [                        
        {
          "key": "instagram",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "twitter",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "facebook",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "tiktok",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Because `media` is an array property, **any document that matches the filter will be used to create buckets**, and I'll have buckets **that don't match my filter**. Here I want to only get back buckets `facebook` and `instagram`, since those are the two that I'm filtering to (via the terms-lookup).

I know terms aggregations offer a [includes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_4) ability, but that doesn't work for me here since I'm using a terms-lookup, and don't know the data in `favorite_media` at query time.

**How can I limit my buckets to be only those that match the filters in my query?**

Thank you for your help!